# Canonical guidance on filesystem choices?

Tags: filesystem

Paying Canonical UA customer, relatively new to Ubuntu, coming from 10+ years of RHEL administration.

I've searched the paywalled Canonical KB, as well as Canonical public sources and haven't found a document similar to Red Hat's "How to Choose Your Red Hat Enterprise Linux File System"[1](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3129891) KB.

Does anyone know of any guidance from Canonical covering rationale for choosing EXT4 as the default OS filesystem, with Canonical specific guidance for when to consider non-default filesystems such as XFS?

Thanks!

Comment: "*Guidance from Canonical*" must come from Canonical employees. Consult your UA service representative. AskUbuntu is community volunteers, not Canonical employees. You will get community answers here.

Comment: We're perfectly happy to offer our opinions and experience...if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks all - I've filed a support ticket with Canonical to see if they offer guidance, but @cocomac, the question you linked seems like the most likely reply I'll get from the UA folks.